# c style thread creation in python

Tags: python

Hi I am new to python and want to create multiple threads in a loop something like (in C style)

```
for (;i < 10; i++)
 thread[i]= pthread_create(&thread[i],&attr,func)
```

I am not sure how to do the same in python? Basically I want have that thread[] variable as global will create all thread at once and then will start then in once. I have written a similar python program that does it but I think having it in above style will be better.

```
def thread_create(thread_number):
    command_string = "Thread-" + "%d" %thread_number
    thread = myThread(thread_number, command_string)
    thread.start()

# Start new Threads

for i in range(5):
    thread_create(i)
```

Comment: What's the problem? Your code appears correct. Can you give an example of what you want your Python code to look like?

Comment: IIRC, you need to store the created threads objects somewhere, otherwise the Python runtime will garbage collect them (i.e., kill them).

Comment: @user1202136: I don't think you technically need to store a reference to them. As long as they are running, I believe they have a reference.

Comment: @user1202136 Running threads are reachable from thread-local interpreter state and will not be garbage-collected as long as their thread is running. It's still a good idea to store them to have an object to call `join` on.

Comment: I think I did not put my question properly. I want to create multiple threads in a loop and also want to save the thread info in a array. So that I could do  thread[2].start.

Comment: And the question is... wait for it... How do I store my threads in a global list! That's your question. Now ask it and you might get the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think this is better?

```
for i in range(5):
    command_string = "Thread-" + "%d" % i
    thread = Thread(i, command_string)
    thread.start()
```

Comment: I am doing this now. I was looking for some way in which I would declare the thread variable globally and I could use it in any other function as thread[2].run or thread[3].start. It will allow me to access the data anywhere. In the existing way I am over writing the same variable again and again in loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 1-to-1 equivalent, then this might be it:

```
threads = []
for i in xrange(10):
    t = Thread(target=aFunc, name="Thread-%d" % i)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
```

Or if you just want to build up the thread objects, and start them later at-will...

```
threads = []
for i in xrange(10):
    t = Thread(target=aFunc, name="Thread-%d" % i)
    threads.append(t)

threads[2].start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Reuse your thread_create function and list comprehension to get what you want.

```
def thread_create(thread_number):
    command_string = "Thread-" + "%d" %thread_number
    return myThread(thread_number, command_string)
    # start them later


# see note below
threads = [thread_create(x) for x in range(5)]

for t in threads:
    t.start()
```

**Note:**

```
threads = [thread_create(x) for x in range(5)]
```

is just shorthand for

```
threads = []
for x in range(5):
    threads.append(thread_create(x))
```